# ComponentScan fails to find classes tagged with @Component

Tags: java, spring

I am following the Confident Spring Professional from  [marco behler](https://www.marcobehler.com/courses/spring-professional)

I am only using the spring context package, nothing else.
I have a configuration class as following

```
package com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.context;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ApplicationLauncher.class)
@Configuration
public class MyFancyPdfInvoicesApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper();
    }
}
```

`UserService.java` as following

```
package com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.service;

import com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.model.User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.UUID;
@Component
public class UserService {

    public User findById(String id) {
        String randomName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        // always "finds" the user, every user has a random name
        return new User(id, randomName);
    }
}
```

MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet.java as following

```
package com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.web;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.*;
import com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.context.MyFancyPdfInvoicesApplicationConfiguration;
import com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.model.Invoice;
import com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.service.InvoiceService;
import com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private UserService userService;
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private InvoiceService invoiceService;

    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx
                = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyFancyPdfInvoicesApplicationConfiguration.class);
        this.userService = ctx.getBean(UserService.class);
        this.objectMapper = ctx.getBean(ObjectMapper.class);
        this.invoiceService = ctx.getBean(InvoiceService.class);
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.shatef.myfancypdfinvoices</groupId>
    <artifactId>myfancypdfinvoices</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>19</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>19</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.54</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

ApplicationLauncher.java

```
package com.shatef.myfancyinvoices;

import com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.web.MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet;
import org.apache.catalina.Context;
import org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException;
import org.apache.catalina.Wrapper;
import org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat;

public class ApplicationLauncher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LifecycleException {

        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setPort(8080);
        tomcat.getConnector();

        Context ctx = tomcat.addContext("", null);
        Wrapper servlet = Tomcat.addServlet(ctx, "myFirstServlet", new MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet());
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/*");

        tomcat.start();
    }
}
```

And the following package structure
[image]

I keep getting the following errors, although `@ComponentScan` is configured for the right package path.

```
No qualifying bean of type 'com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.service.UserService' available
```

Stack trace

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:3.1.0:java (default-cli) @ myfancypdfinvoices ---
Jan 28, 2023 1:44:26 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Jan 28, 2023 1:44:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jan 28, 2023 1:44:26 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.54]
Jan 28, 2023 1:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.service.UserService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.web.MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet.init(MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$ExistingStandardWrapper.loadServlet(Tomcat.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 24 more
Jan 28, 2023 1:44:27 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:926)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.service.UserService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.web.MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet.init(MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$ExistingStandardWrapper.loadServlet(Tomcat.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 24 more
[WARNING] 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal (StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:486)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher.main (ApplicationLauncher.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report (FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal (StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:486)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher.main (ApplicationLauncher.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:938)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal (StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal (StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:486)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher.main (ApplicationLauncher.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report (FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get (FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:926)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal (StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal (StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:486)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher.main (ApplicationLauncher.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException (LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal (StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal (StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:486)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher.main (ApplicationLauncher.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1589)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.service.UserService' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean (DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean (AbstractApplicationContext.java:1172)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.web.MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet.init (MyFancyPdfInvoicesServlet.java:27)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init (GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$ExistingStandardWrapper.loadServlet (Tomcat.java:1241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load (StandardWrapper.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup (StandardContext.java:4957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal (StandardContext.java:5264)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal (StandardHost.java:835)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1396)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call (ContainerBase.java:1386)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:317)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute (InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit (AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal (ContainerBase.java:919)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal (StandardEngine.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal (StandardService.java:432)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal (StandardServer.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start (LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start (Tomcat.java:486)
    at com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher.main (ApplicationLauncher.java:22)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run (ExecJavaMojo.java:279)
    at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:1589)
```

Comment: What is the full stack trace?

Comment: Your example works fine here (I've removed the InvoiceService and guessed what the content of your ApplicationLauncher is). You should probably share a complete example which definitely fails.

Comment: This may seem obvious but have you tried deleting the target folder, wiping the IDE cache and rebuilding the project completely? Sometimes IDEs can keep stuff in memory or as temp files on the disk and that can mess up the application.

Comment: @HeroWanders, I added the Application Launcher. The rest of the files are just POJOs. 
Is there a way to print debug statements related to the component scanner ? 
May this be related to JDK version ?

Comment: @ShadyAtef just had another thought, make sure your SDK is set properly in the project settings.

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz I tried invalidating the cache of the IDE. 
I even went to the cmdline executing the following `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=com.shatef.myfancyinvoices.ApplicationLauncher` and still gets the same error

Comment: Try specifying the target source SDK in the shade plugin, looking at the documentation it seems there are props there to fill https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ManifestResourceTransformer , also looks like your props are not structured the same as in the docs.

Comment: Just a little note: To make your code work, I actually had to update the version of `org.springframework:spring-context` to at least `5.3.14` because this is the version which introduced Java 19 support (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/releases/tag/v5.3.14).

Comment: @HeroWanders, I tried with Java 17 and I tried to update to `5.3.14` . Still the same error.

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz, I tried that also. I think it's something related to maven. 
As when I use the intellij build system, it works.

Comment: I've compiled the application into a runnable jar file (let's call it `stack.jar`) with `mvn package` and ran it using `java -jar stack.jar`. It started fine and don't see any dependency on IntelliJ here.

Comment: @HeroWanders, this also works on my side.  I think it's something related to `mvn exec` command.

I added the full project to here: https://github.com/ShadyAbuKalam/myfancypdfinvoices